# Как преобразовать строку в числовую функцию

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется вот такой вариант калькулятора, в данном случае при нажатии на кнопку равно, проводится сбор в строковом значении, как его перевести в нужный мне формат? То есть если ввести **3+3**, этот код соберёт его и выведет в виде текста, а нужно, чтоб он посчитал сумму(в зависимости от выбранной операции).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var mat = $(this).text();
    var rounded = $('.inputCalc').val() + mat;
    $('.inputCalc').val(rounded);
  })
  $('.remove').click(function() {
    $('.inputCalc').val('');
  })
  $('.equal').click(function() {
    var equal = ($('.inputCalc').val());

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calc rounded p-3">
  <div class="col-xs-12 m-b-3 m-t-3">
    <input type="text" disabled class="inputCalc text-right m-3 p-3 rounded">
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <button value="1" class="buttonCalc m-1 numeral rounded">1</button>
    <button value="2" class="buttonCalc m-1 numeral rounded">2</button>
    <button value="3" class="buttonCalc m-1 numeral rounded">3</button>
    <button value="+" class="buttonCalc m-1 greenBut rounded">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <button value="4" class="buttonCalc m-1 numeral rounded">4</button>
    <button value="5" class="buttonCalc m-1 numeral rounded">5</button>
    <button value="6" class="buttonCalc m-1 numeral rounded">6</button>
    <button value="-" class="buttonCalc m-1 blueDarkBut rounded">-</button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <button value="7" class="buttonCalc m-1 numeral rounded">7</button>
    <button value="8" class="buttonCalc m-1 numeral rounded">8</button>
    <button value="9" class="buttonCalc m-1 numeral rounded">9</button>
    <button value="*" class="buttonCalc m-1 yellowBut rounded">*</button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <button value="0" class="buttonCalcZer m-1 numeral rounded">0</button>
    <button class="buttonCalcZer m-1 rounded remove">AC</button>
    <button value="/" class="buttonCalc m-1 blueBut rounded">/</button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <button class="equal m-1 rounded">=</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой "волшебной" функции не существует (кроме `eval` - спасибо за комментарий пользователю [@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy)). Нужно парсить или использовать внешнюю библиотеку, которая, собственно, делает то же самое. Решение "на коленке" используя Ваш код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var mat = $(this).text();
    var rounded = $('.inputCalc').val() + mat;
    $('.inputCalc').val(rounded);
  })
  $('.remove').click(function() {
    $('.inputCalc').val('');
  })
  $('.equal').click(function() {
    $('.inputCalc').val(math.eval($('.inputCalc').val().replace(/=/, '')));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/5.4.2/math.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calc rounded p-3">
  <div class="col-xs-12 m-b-3 m-t-3">
    <input type="text" disabled class="inputCalc text-right m-3 p-3 rounded">
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <button value="1" class="buttonCalc m-1 numeral rounded">1</button>
    <button value="2" class="buttonCalc m-1 numeral rounded">2</button>
    <button value="3" class="buttonCalc m-1 numeral rounded">3</button>
    <button value="+" class="buttonCalc m-1 greenBut rounded">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <button value="4" class="buttonCalc m-1 numeral rounded">4</button>
    <button value="5" class="buttonCalc m-1 numeral rounded">5</button>
    <button value="6" class="buttonCalc m-1 numeral rounded">6</button>
    <button value="-" class="buttonCalc m-1 blueDarkBut rounded">-</button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <button value="7" class="buttonCalc m-1 numeral rounded">7</button>
    <button value="8" class="buttonCalc m-1 numeral rounded">8</button>
    <button value="9" class="buttonCalc m-1 numeral rounded">9</button>
    <button value="*" class="buttonCalc m-1 yellowBut rounded">*</button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <button value="0" class="buttonCalcZer m-1 numeral rounded">0</button>
    <button class="buttonCalcZer m-1 rounded remove">AC</button>
    <button value="/" class="buttonCalc m-1 blueBut rounded">/</button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <button class="equal m-1 rounded">=</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Здесь используется библиотека [Math.js](http://mathjs.org/) (но не обязательно именно её использовать). На `$('.equal').click` повесил преобразование строки `$('.inputCalc').val()` (у которой предварительно убирается знак "**=**"). Эта строка входит в качестве аргумента в `math.eval` (как раз работает библиотека, документация приведена [здесь](http://mathjs.org/docs/index.html)). И полученный результат записывается обратно в `$('.inputCalc').val()`. Решение не идеально, но рабочее. Здесь важно было показать не "суперкомпактность", а пример, как можно преобразовать значение строки, например, "**3+3**" в значение "**6**", а также сохранить по максимуму код автора.

Comment: Решение, может быть, и подходящее. Но т.к. нет никаких объяснений, что, где и почему делается, то поставил минус.

Comment: Я добавил лишь одну строчку, какие Вам нужны объяснения?

Comment: Куда добавил? Что эта строчка делает? Ответ должен быть объясняющим и обучающим, а не заставлять искать что и где изменилось.

Comment: Я добавил описание, просьба не судить строго.

Comment: Ну вот, теперь твердый плюс!

Comment: @Kvilios, _Такой "волшебной" функции не существует._ а как же `eval`?

Comment: @Grundy eval is evil)
Опасная функция, но спасибо за дополнение к ответу, правда на практике (лично я) никогда не применял её из соображений безопасности.

Comment: @Kvilios, формально eval Не больший evil чем наличие devtools в браузере, ну и если не пихать в него неизвестно откуда взявшуюся строку - все ок :)